# verbose rakefile - print all executed command lines to stdout

Tags: ruby, debugging, makefile, verbose

I've just began building my first Rakefile (Ruby version of makefile), and I'd like to debug my script easily using verbose mode (like makefile -V or bash -x) is there an option to do so on ruby ?

thanks

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`rake --trace` will probably give you everything you need